# Error: NG0900: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only array and iterable are allowed

Tags: angular, angularjs

Currently, I'm working on a MovieTicketBooking website using Angular and an asp.net web API. It got stuck at one point where I could not fix it. When I try to display movie details on the frontend, I get errors like this `Error: NG0900: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed`. Please help me to solve it

book.component.html

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body" *ngFor="let item of moviedata">
      <h5 class="card-title">{{item.Title}}</h5>
      <p class="card-text">{{item.Description}}</p>
      <!-- <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="getAllMovieById(item.id)">Book</button> -->
    </div>
</div>
```

book.component.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Movie } from 'src/app/Models/Movie';
import { MovieService } from 'src/app/shared/movie.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-book',
  templateUrl: './book.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./book.component.css']
})
export class BookComponent implements OnInit {
  moviedata: Movie[] = [];

  constructor(private route : ActivatedRoute , private formBuilder : FormBuilder, private _http:HttpClient, private router: Router, private movieservice : MovieService) { 

    this.movieservice.getMovieById(this.route.snapshot.params['id']).subscribe((result:any)=>{
      this.moviedata = result;
      console.log(this.moviedata);
    })
  }

  ngOnInit(): void 
  {
  }
}
```

Data on Console

```
autoOffSet: null
createdBy: 0
creationDate: "0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"
description: "qwerty"
entityState: 0
fare: 123
id: 1
imgPath: null
modifiedBy: null
modifiedDate: null
rowVersion: null
shows: Array(1)
0: {ticket: 12, showTime: '2022-05-23T13:09:00', showDate: '2022-05-23T00:00:00', movieId: 1, movie: {…}, …}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
title: "Doctor Strange"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `moviedata` is an object, not an array.

You should do like this.

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body" >
      <h5 class="card-title">{{moviedata.title}}</h5>
      <p class="card-text">{{moviedata.description}}</p>
      <!-- <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="getAllMovieById(item.id)">Book</button> -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
this.moviedata = result;
```

`result` isn't an object; you should parse it to get an object:

```js
this.moviedata = JSON.parse(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `result` wasn't type `Movie[]`. This might help to being your idea.

```
 constructor(private route : ActivatedRoute , private formBuilder : FormBuilder, private _http:HttpClient, private router: Router, private movieservice : MovieService) {
   this.movieservice.getMovieById(this.route.snapshot.params['id']).subscribe((result:any)=>{
     console.log('result', result);
     this.moviedata = result.shows;
     console.log(this.moviedata);
   })
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is as a result of how the backend sent it API so you have to first get the object value then convert it to an array and pass the index of the data you want to pick.
e.g
0
:
true
1
:
200
2
:
null
3
:
(73) [{…}, {…}.......,{..}]

from the above the status is on index 0; the statuscode on 1,message on index 2 then the data on index 3
this.moviedata = Object.values(result)[3];

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).